# How to make input-group in a table reasonably sized in bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

If I place a input-group with an input-group-btn in a cell in a table, that column tries to take up as much space as possible.  Is there a good way to limit that?  Have I used the BS3 styles incorrectly?

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Mn5u5/1

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <td>test 1</td>
        <td>test 2</td>
        <td>test 3</td>
        <td>test 4</td>
        <td>test 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-small btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>test 2</td>
        <td>test 3</td>
        <td>test 4</td>
        <td>test 5</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: adding width='30%' to the td seems to help, but is the the right solution? http://jsfiddle.net/Mn5u5/2/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap form-controls are set to `width:100%` by default. The most straight forward option is as follows:

1. Set explicit widths on the `<td>`. Note that you only need to do this once per column. I would suggest on the column's `<th>`, assuming you have one.

Comment: Is there any chance you could link a jsfiddle that worked for #2?  I tried setting the size on a few different elements and unless it was a size on the column itself, I didn't have any luck.

Comment: That is weird. I didn't actually try it, since I have used that trick before on fields, but never fields that were in table cells. Putting it on the `.input-group` seemed to resize the input down for me, but the table cell size did not change, which is really odd. I am going to remove #2 from my answer until I have a chance to sort it out.

Comment: Better yet, set width to inherit so it'll get its width from parent and basically set it back to what it was supposed to be